# If $X$ and $Y$ are finite sets, given that $X \cap Y \subseteq X$, it implies that $X\cap Y$ is a finite set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm asking just to make sure.

I'm intending to use the proposition that asserts that if $A$ is a finite set and $B \subseteq A$, then $B$ is a finite set.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A subset of a finite set has smaller cardinal, so it will be finite too.

Comment: The intersection of two subsets is a subset of both of them separately. This means one of $X$ or $Y$ can be infinite and one finite and the intersection will still be finite.

Comment: @SiriusG. Yeah, you are right. But I need to pretend that I do not know it in the text I'm writing. haha

Comment: Are you pretending you don't know the proposition you quote in your post? Because that, and the definition of intersection, are the only two things you need.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I agree with you. So the hypothesis $Y$ finite can be removed.

Comment: @Arthur I'm pretending that I do not know that a subset of a finite set has a smaller cardinal than the set. I want to use the proposition I quoted to base to prove the question. I'm almost convinced, but I came here to have other opinions.

Comment: @fourier $X\cap Y$ is a subset of $X$. Using the prop. you quote it will be a finite set.

Comment: @SiriusG. OK! Thank you.